# I wanna generate custom error from okhttp3.Response in Authenticator class

Tags: android, authentication, retrofit, okhttp

**Question in nutshel:**

I wanna read custom error from **okhttp3.Response** like what I do from **retrofit2.Response**!

**Question in detail:**

On okhttp3 Authenticator I wanna read Response custom error to check if my 401 is related to token expired then try to continue on authenticate method and create new request with new tokens.
Backend gimme custom error like this and I can read it's enum type ( as code) and decide what to do next.

```
{
 "timestamp": "2020-11-24T16:55:03.365+09:00",
 "status": 401,
 "code": "UNAUTHENTICATED_USER",
 "message": "The user is not authenticated",
 "path": "/members"
}
```

So main problem is I can not read custom error message from **okhttp3.Response**! While i can do this from **retrofit2.Response** like this:

```
@Keep
data class CustomError(
    val timestamp: String?,
    val status: Int,
    val code: ErrorCodes,
    val message: String?,
    val path: String?
)

fun  generateCustomError(response : Response<Any>):CustomError {

    return try {
        val gson = Gson()
        val myError: CustomError = gson.fromJson(
            response.errorBody()?.charStream(),
            CustomError::class.java
        )
        myError
    }catch (e: Exception){
        CustomError(null,response.code(),ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN,response.message(),null)
    }
}
```

But seems that ***okhttp3.Response*** does not have any errorBody. So how I can generate custom error from ?

Comment: the body is also used for error payloads

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found that I can get it from:

```
response.body?.charStream()
```

So I create second method like this:

```
fun  generateCustomErrorFromReader(code: Int, message:String, stream : Reader?):CustomError {
    return try {
        val gson = Gson()
        val myError: CustomError = gson.fromJson(
            stream,
            CustomError::class.java
        )

    //because of gson reflection, the code may be null if the response is empty
    if (myError.code == null) {
        CustomError(null,code,ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN,message,null)
    } else {
        myError
    }
}catch (e: Exception){
    CustomError(null,code,ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN,message,null)
```